# Accessing Swift Extension From Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, swift-extensions

I'm having trouble accessing my swift extension from objective-c.

I have the following code in a .swift file:

```
extension NSDictionary {
    func dictionaryAsJsonString() -> NSString {
        var err: NSError?
        var data = NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(self, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted, error: &err)
        var string = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        return string
    }
}
```

I'm expecting to be able to do the following in my .m file:

```
[dictionary dictionaryAsJsonString];
```

but it can't find my method and doesn't autocomplete.

I know my imports are working fine because I'm able to access my other swift objects.

Comment: Did you figure out how to call the extensions from Objective-C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy enough using simply a Dictionary

```
 20> extension Dictionary {
 21.     func toJSONString () -> String { return "my dictionary" }
 22. }
 23> ["a": 1, "b": 2].toJSONString()
$R10: String = "my dictionary"
```

The Apple documentation does not mention using extensions on Objective-C classes.

Comment: In the documentation, they mention how extensions are analogous to categories (which is something you can do this way).

Though I haven't tried it yet, I'm assuming that if I have a category on an existing obj-c class, I'll be able to access those methods via swift. But according to what you said, it doesn't work the other way?

Answer (score 1):

This was probably a bug, or incomplete implementation, in the early version you tried in June. It works just fine to extend NSDictionary in latest beta. For example, this *very* complicated extension and usage works as expected, with code completion:

```
extension NSDictionary {
    func myFooBar() {
        println("gaaah")
    }
}

// elsewhere...

var d = NSDictionary(object: "bar", forKey: "foo")
d.myFooBar()
```

Comment: as of XCode Version 7.1.1 (7B1005) Doing the elsewhere part in objective c does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1):

In short:

File configuration setup:

```
CustomClass.h
CustomClass.m
CustomClassExtension.swift
```

In CustomClassExtension:

```
@objc extension CustomClass
{
    func method1() 
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

In any other class:

```
self.customClass = [[CustomClass alloc] init];
[self.customClass method1];
```